# maven with bouncycastle jar error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, bouncycastle

I am using the following dependecy in my pom.xml from maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.55</version>
</dependency>
```

After running the project inside eclipse everything is working fine.
By using the export feature from eclipse, creating a runnable jar file, including all dependencies also everything works fine.
No other parameters or configurations in eclipse are set.

Only when i am running a mvn built something seems to be wrong.
(Maven built runs without any error or warnings)
--> Dependencies are all included.

An error occurs in that moment when it tries to establish an https connection, the place where this bouncycastle library is used.

Error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: Could not derive key
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:553)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:412)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at plugin.KITIlias.executePost(KITIlias.java:117)
        at plugin.KITIlias.login(KITIlias.java:45)
        at control.IliasManager.login(IliasManager.java:27)
        at control.IliasStarter.login(IliasStarter.java:31)
        at control.LoginProvider$1.run(LoginProvider.java:56)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: Could not derive key
        at sun.security.ec.ECDHKeyAgreement.engineGenerateSecret(ECDHKeyAgreement.java:133)
        at sun.security.ec.ECDHKeyAgreement.engineGenerateSecret(ECDHKeyAgreement.java:163)
        at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.generateSecret(KeyAgreement.java:648)
        at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.getAgreedSecret(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
        at sun.security.ec.ECDHKeyAgreement.deriveKey(Native Method)
        at sun.security.ec.ECDHKeyAgreement.engineGenerateSecret(ECDHKeyAgreement.java:130)
        ... 25 more
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at plugin.KITIlias.executePost(KITIlias.java:125)
        at plugin.KITIlias.login(KITIlias.java:45)
        at control.IliasManager.login(IliasManager.java:27)
        at control.IliasStarter.login(IliasStarter.java:31)
        at control.LoginProvider$1.run(LoginProvider.java:56)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So for me it seems like something is missing during the maven built process.
Is it required to sign one of the jars?

my complete pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>X</groupId>
    <artifactId>Y</artifactId>
    <version>v1.1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>8.20.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.55</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>view.Dashboard</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am getting the runnable jar with:

```
mvn clean install
```

EDIT:
Manifest file from eclipse export

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ junit-4.10.jar hamcrest-core-1.1.jar log4j-1.2.17.
 jar jsoup-1.7.2.jar httpcore-4.4.5.jar httpclient-4.5.2.jar commons-c
 odec-1.9.jar commons-logging-1.1.1.jar controlsfx-8.20.8.jar openjfx-
 dialogs-1.0.2.jar bcprov-jdk15on-1.55.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: view.Dashboard
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

-> seems like there are still dependencies to eclipse

Comment: Seems to me that your maven is using a different java when compared to eclipse. And this java version which is being used by maven might not have security certificates installed on it. Are you working in a company ?

Comment: Maven, Eclipse, OS -> all are using the same java version. I am not working in a company no. Isn't it that all certificates are part of the jvm? and nothing specific to eclipse or maven?

Comment: I am seeing this exact issue. I am working in a company. The develop branch does not have this issue. It's just my branch that has this issue. Could it be related to dependencies? Because I have added a few dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Problem seems to be here that the dependency from bouncycastle must be signed. The jar is not signed anymore if maven repacks it inside another jar.
Solution is to keep all dependecies next to the jar file and add a classpathdirectory. Now the main jar can use directly the signed jar.

(However i would really prefer to have one single jar file)

Comment: There is an issue with "shading" or "1-jar-ing" Bouncy Castle (and other signed jars), but I don't think that's this particular issue.  For the signing thing, what I've always done is 1 jar the java classes only (exclude META-INF signing stuff) and then re-sign with my own certificate.  For this particular issue, I'm hitting it too and haven't yet found an answer.